# sql server multiple choice

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

**I want to allow to table linked to another table multiple choice**

For example, a customer table linked to a region table.

How to allow a customer table to get several area IDs in the same field

Comment: Hi, does running locally with the heroku cli work? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally

Comment: I’m afraid the the provided information is not enough. Are you able to share your repository or maybe create a codesandbox

Comment: No I mean, that the information you provided is not enough to find out what the problem is. If you can share your code if would be great if you upload it to https://github.com/ and then share it here.